# Opencart 3 changes in Admin not saving

Tags: opencart-3

I have a recently installed OpenCart 3 site and anytime I make a change in the admin panel as I am setting up this site the changes are not saving. I do not see any errors in any error log in the Bluehost hosting account.

I am wondering if anyone might have some suggestions. I saw one other post that talked about going into my phpmyadmin and going to the settings table and making sure there is a column labeled code which there is. I also saw another post talking about making sure mod_security is disabled. However according to Blue Host that is disabled by default .

I am looking for other suggestions
thank you